# How do I get a navbar to only show on the product category page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a navbar that I only want to appear on the product category page on my woocommerce site. Does anybody know what php or javascript code I need to make this happen? Thanks in advance!

HTML of the navbar (currently in the index.php file)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="91" id="search-nav"></nav>
```

Note: I'm using Wordpress, Woocommerce and Twitter Bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce provides the `is_product_category()` conditional to check if the user is viewing a product category archive page:

```
<?php if( is_product_category() ): ?>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="91" id="search-nav"></nav>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a custom header with your navbar and then call it on the category-page template like this:

```
<?php get_header( 'your-custom-header' ); ?>
```